# ADO.NET and SSMS interpret SP params differently or SQL profiler has a bug?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

Try to be brief. Here is my table and SP in SQL Server 2008 R2 database:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_TABLE
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    VALUE varchar(23)
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE USP_TEST_PROCEDURE
( 
    @Param1 varchar(23)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (VALUE) VALUES (@Param1)
END
GO
```

Here is the C# code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = GetConection())
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_TEST_PROCEDURE", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.DateTime, 23).Value = "2013-12-10 12:34:56.789";
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Pay attention that I intentionally specified the type of @Param1 as DateTime.
Now launch SQL Server Profiler and run the .NET code. When done, don’t stop the profiler, just look at the output. I see the following text for the RPC:Completed EventClass:

```
exec USP_TEST_PROCEDURE @Param1='2013-12-10 12:34:56.790'
```

Now copy this text, open SSMS, paste to the new query window and run it **without any changes**. Now stop the profiler and make sure that the SSMS produced the same text in the profiler as ADO.NET app:

```
exec USP_TEST_PROCEDURE @Param1='2013-12-10 12:34:56.790'
```

Now select from the TEST_TABLE table. I see the following result:

> ```
> ID VALUE
> 1  Dec 10 2013 12:34PM
> 2  2013-12-10 12:34:56.790
> ```

The question is why the two identical commands (from SQL Server Profiler’s point of view) produce different results?

It seems like profiler does not show correctly what is going on behind the scene. After I ran the .NET app I expected to see the following:

```
DECLARE @Param1 Datetime = '2013-12-10 12:34:56.789';
exec USP_TEST_PROCEDURE @Param1=@Param1
```

In this case it would be clear why I have 790 milliseconds instead of 789. This is because the datetime type is not very precise. It is rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds. See: [datetime (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) It would be also clear why I have ‘Dec 10 2013 12:34PM’ instead of ‘2013-12-10 12:34:56.790’. This is because ‘mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)’ format is used by default when datetime is converted to string. See [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) The following example demonstrates that:

```
DECLARE @Param1 Datetime = '2013-12-10 12:34:56.789';
DECLARE @Param1_varchar varchar(23);

SELECT @Param1 --2013-12-10 12:34:56.790
SET @Param1_varchar = @Param1;
SELECT @Param1_varchar; --Dec 10 2013 12:34PM
GO
```

If my understanding is correct, then I would like to rephrase the question: Why SQL Server Profiler shows something strange and confusing? Are there any options to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Your application is sending a datetime, but since you chose a varchar column, it is implicitly converted on the way in. Just like what happens with print:

```sql
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT @d; -- this is still a datetime

PRINT @d; -- this is implicitly converted to a string
```

If you don't like this confusing behavior, then stop mixing data types. There is absolutely no good reason to store a datetime value in a varchar column.

Comment: Yes, you are right - we should not mix data types. However, I would like to pay attention that I did it intentionally to reveal the problem. As a matter of fact, the question is about the confusing behavior of SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Let’s imagine I have a 3rd party application and don’t have access to the source code. So I don’t know what SqlDbType is assigned to SqlParameter. Maybe it has SqlDbType.DateTime or maybe SqlDbType.VarChar. In this case the only way to see what is going on is to use profiler. So I launch it and see the following:

`exec USP_TEST_PROCEDURE @Param1='2013-12-10 12:34:56.790'`

How do I know that the “application is sending a datetime”, not a string? It is not obvious. Is there any parameter in the profiler that can force the profiler to show this information?

Comment: @Alex I think you're using the wrong tool for the wrong job, and I don't even know why. For one, profiler is deprecated, never mind that it was not designed for the task you're doing. And you can get a lot more information out of the execution plan (parameter types, implicit converts, etc.) than you'll ever get out of profiler. You're trying to ask the cab driver who drove me to the airport what time I'll land at my destination.